Extract some values from string
I receive text from response:
"Generate something in 1:1 format for Birthday in an cheerful, celebratory mood. The image should be created in an Graffiti style. The text Happy Birthday! is at the top. At the bottom is the lettering: Liam. Graphic elements should visually reflect the terms stars, balloons."
and have string without values ready:
const sub = "Generate something in 1:1 format for in an mood. The image should be created in an style. The text is at the top. At the bottom is the lettering:. Graphic elements should visually reflect the terms.";

In every response words can differ, for example Birthday->Thank You, Liam->John Doe, stars, balloons->fireworks and many other combinations.
Also, basic strings, prompt and sub can be in different languages.
Is there a way to extract marked words (which will be used to prefil some input fields)?
I managed to do that only if the words are quoted like:


const sub = "Generate something in 1:1 format for in an mood. The image should be created in an style. The text is at the top. At the bottom is the lettering:. Graphic elements should visually reflect the terms."

const prompt = "Generate something in 1:1 format for 'Birthday' in an 'cheerful, celebratory' mood. The image should be created in an 'Graffiti' style. The text 'Happy Birthday!' is at the top. At the bottom is the lettering: 'Liam'. Graphic elements should visually reflect the terms 'stars, balloons'."

const resolvePrompt = (prompt, sub) => {
  return prompt
    .replaceAll(".", "")
    .split(" ")
    .filter((wd) => !sub.includes(wd))
    .join("")
    .split("''");
};
  
console.log(resolvePrompt(prompt, sub))




do you have backtick \`` or single quotes '` as delimiters?

@qqq hey mate, no like You can see from attached snippet if there are quotes I have a solution, but will receive just a plain text not backticks, no quotes

@Yogi hey mate, they are market as a differences from the sub variable

You can walk through one of the word arrays checking if each word matches the current word in the other array, and keeping track of those that don't.
Note, if your prompt doesn't properly match your sub, this might crash/infinite loop/break unless proper steps are taken to safeguard it.


const sub = "Generate something in 1:1 format for in an mood. The image should be created in an style. The text is at the top. At the bottom is the lettering:. Graphic elements should visually reflect the terms."

const prompt = "Generate something in 1:1 format for 'Birthday' in an 'cheerful, celebratory' mood. The image should be created in an 'Graffiti' style. The text 'Happy Birthday!' is at the top. At the bottom is the lettering: 'Liam'. Graphic elements should visually reflect the terms 'stars, balloons'."

const re = /[\.\s]+/;

const sa = sub.split(re);
const pa = prompt.split(re);
const output = [];

for (let si = 0, pi = 0; si < sa.length; si++) {
  const part = [];
  while (sa[si] != pa[pi]) {
    part.push(pa[pi]);
    pi++;
  }
  if (part.length) output.push(part.join(" "));
  pi++;
}

console.log(output);




If my guess is right, I think the problem could be solved like this:


const variablePattern = /'([\w\d\s,.;!?\\\-+*=/_\[\]\(\)\{\}@#$%&]*)'/g;

function generateVariableString ( thePrompt )
{
  let theIndex = 0;
  
  const variableMatches = thePrompt.matchAll(variablePattern);
  
  for ( const [ theVariable, theContent ] of variableMatches )
  {
    thePrompt = thePrompt.replace(theVariable, `\${${theIndex++}}`);
  }
  
  return thePrompt;
}

function parseVariableString ( thePrompt, theKeyValuePairs )
{
  for ( const theIndex in theKeyValuePairs )
  {
    thePrompt = thePrompt.replace(`\${${theIndex}}`, theKeyValuePairs[theIndex]);
  }
  
  return thePrompt;
}

// TESTS

var thePrompt = "Generate something in 1:1 format for 'Birthday' in an 'cheerful, celebratory' mood. The image should be created in an 'Graffiti' style. The text 'Happy Birthday!' is at the top. At the bottom is the lettering: 'Liam'. Graphic elements should visually reflect the terms 'stars, balloons'.";

var newWords = ['Marriage', 'crazy, frenzy', 'Neon', 'CRAZIEST', 'WEDDING', 'dance, music, popularity, wetty'];

var variablePrompt = generateVariableString(thePrompt);

var parsedPrompt = parseVariableString(variablePrompt, newWords);


// LOGS

console.log('newWords =', newWords);
console.log('thePrompt =', thePrompt);
console.log('variablePrompt =', variablePrompt);
console.log('parsedPrompt =', parsedPrompt);

var namedVariables = ['${Theme}', '${Mood}', '${Style}', '${TopText}', '${BottomText}', '${Terms}'];

console.log('NEW named variablePrompt =', parseVariableString(variablePrompt, namedVariables));

// MORE TESTS

var variableText = "This is ${Name}, ${Pronoun} works at the ${Workplace} near ${Nearplace}.";
var variableMap =
{
  Name: 'Anonymous',
  Pronoun: 'he',
  Workplace: 'bank',
  Nearplace: 'my house',
}

var parsedText = parseVariableString(variableText, variableMap);

// MORE LOGS

console.log('variableMap =', variableMap);
console.log('variableText =', variableText);
console.log('parsedText =', parsedText);



NOTE that it would be useful to add as many punctuations in the following pattern as possible:
const variablePattern = /'([\w\d\s,.;!?\\\-+*=/_\[\]\(\)\{\}@#$%&]*)'/g;

IMPORTANT: The parseVariableString can use both an array or an object as theKeyValuePairs parameter.
PS.1: I made the placeholder like ${<VARIABLE>} where <VARIABLE> is your key to make easier to generate javascript dynamically.
PS.2: Generated variable strings would work only with numeric keys. But you can parse then using an array and replacing the placeholders with new named placeholders.

You just need to use few regex, if you are new, you can ask AI to make it for you.
Here:

We are using (.+?) where .+ together matches one or more than one character in sequence until default pattern follows, ? makes matching less greedy,i.e it will match least possible until it gets back to track.
.match(regex) return corresponding matches from which we extract content in order



const responseText = "Generate something in 1:1 format for Birthday in an cheerful, celebratory mood. The image should be created in an Graffiti style. The text Happy Birthday! is at the top. At the bottom is the lettering: Liam. Graphic elements should visually reflect the terms stars, balloons."; // or use input


const sub = "Generate something in 1:1 format for in an mood. The image should be created in an style. The text is at the top. At the bottom is the lettering:. Graphic elements should visually reflect the terms."; // Template string

// You may extend this to full match,though it is unnecessary, like matching here is done only in necessary sentance,not from start of paragraph
const regex = /for (.+?) in an (.+?) mood\. The image should be created in an (.+?) style\. The text (.+?) is at the top\. At the bottom is the lettering: (.+?)\. Graphic elements should visually reflect the terms (.+?)\./;

const matches = responseText.match(regex);

if (matches) {
  const [fullMatch, occasion, mood, style, textTop, textBottom, terms] = matches;
  console.log({
    occasion,
    mood,
    style,
    textTop,
    textBottom,
    terms
  });
}




hey mate, thanks a lot for the answer! It works perfectly , but sadly I can not use it because basic strings may be in many different languages, so I can not hardcode anything from sub variable. Sorry my bad forgot to mention that in a question

How does that make difference, like what you mean is prompt as well as sub can have different language other than english, that doesnt cause any problem right? like can you explain what problem would that be causing like..

like this, german example: "Generiere etwas im 1:1 Format zu {occasion} in einer {adjective} Stimmung. Das Bild soll im Stil {style} angelegt werden. Oben steht der Schriftzug {title}. Am unteren Rand steht der Schriftzug: {name}. Grafische Elemente sollen die Begriffe {keywords} visuell widerspiegeln."

okay so put that accordingly in regex, so why do you worry?

@NikolaPavicevic, it looks like you have delimiter { and } whee is the problem?
